# A unit of a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

This is chahpter 1 exercise 55 of Measure Theory by Bogachev

Suppose we are given a set $X$ and a collection $\mathcal{S}$ of its subsets such that the union of all sets in $\mathcal{S}$ is $Y \subset X$. Prove that the following conditions are equivalent:

(i) $Y$ is an at most countable union of sets in $\mathcal{S}$;

(ii) there exists a smallest family of sets $\mathcal{A}$ with the following properties: $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on some subset $Z \subset X$ (i.e., $Z$ is the unit of this $\sigma$-algebra) and $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathcal{A}$, where a smallest family is a family that is contained in every other family with the stated properties. Consider the example where $X=[0,1], Y=[0,1 / 2], \mathcal{S}$ is the class of all at most countable subsets of $Y$.

I'm having trouble with the forward direction. We can say, since $Y$ is a countable union of elements in $\mathcal{S}$, i.e. $Y = \bigcup_iV_i$ for $V_i \in \mathcal{S}$. Let $\mathcal{A} = \sigma(V_1, V_2,...)$. But how do we write this as $\sigma(Z)$ for $Z \subset X$?